# Capture an integer between 1-100

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to capture a number between 1 and 100 in C#, I would like to loop the user until they enter the correct result. I have the following but it isn't evaluating like I expect, where is the gap in my knowledge?

```
var input=0;

Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");

while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) && input>0 && input <=100)
{
    Console.Write("The value must be a number greater than 0, but less than 100 please try again: ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing a pair of parenthesis and `!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)` is evaluated and false if the user inputs anything.

Try with:

```
var input=0;

Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");

while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) && input>0 && input <=100))
{
    Console.Write("The value must be a number greater than 0, but less than 100 please try again: ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = 0;
        Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");
        while (true)
        {
          if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) && (input < 0 || input > 100))
            {
                Console.Write("The value must be a number greater than 0, but less than 100 please try again: ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you for the correct input");
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();        

    }
```